# Import Error: No Module Named Common - problems with py2exe

Tags: python, dll, exe, py2exe, reportlab

I have a script that starts like this with many imports:

```
from reportlab.graphics import shapes
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from reportlab.graphics import barcode
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import stringWidth
import reportlab.rl_settings
import PIL
from cStringIO import StringIO
import labels
import pyodbc
import pandas
from os.path import expanduser
from time import sleep
import sys
```

I struggled massively with py2exe to even get an executable file. I finally managed it with the following setup script (most of which is just copy and pasted from similar issues and suggests on stackoverflow).

```
from distutils.core import setup
import distutils
import py2exe
import sys
import zmq
import os

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

distutils.core.setup(
    options = {
        "py2exe": {
            "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"]
        }
    },
)

sys.path.append('C:\\WINDOWS\\WinSxS\\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_5090ab56bcba71c2')

packages=[
    'reportlab',
    'reportlab.graphics'
    'reportlab.lib.utils'
    'reportlab.rl_settings'
    'reportlab.lib.units'
    'reportlabl.pdfbase.pdfmetrics',

], 

os.environ["PATH"] = \
    os.environ["PATH"] + \
    os.path.pathsep + os.path.split(zmq.__file__)[0]

setup( console=[{"script": "working.py"}],
       options={ 
           "py2exe": { 
               "includes": 
               ["zmq.utils", "zmq.utils.jsonapi", 
                "zmq.utils.strtypes"] } } )
```

I am sure my script is inelegant. It has three connected define functions and a final output.

```
try:
    makeyourlabels()
except:
    Print "Sorry, something went wrong."
```

I get an error when I run the file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "working.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "reportlab\graphics\barcode\__init__.pyc", line 72, in <module>
  File "reportlab\graphics\barcode\__init__.pyc", line 42, in _reset
  File "reportlab\graphics\barcode\widgets.pyc", line 162, in <module>
  File "reportlab\graphics\barcode\widgets.pyc", line 95, in _BCW
  File "reportlab\lib\utils.pyc", line 243, in rl_exec
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named common
```

If anyone can make any sense of all this and get my .exe running, I would be ever grateful!

Answer (score 0):

As there is no testable code in the question I can not guarantee this will fix your issue but I can explain why you get this error. It is because `py2exe` didn't bundle `reportlab.graphics.barcode.common` into your .exe.

How do I know this, I followed the traceback to see what Reportlab was doing in the `rl_exec` call, it turns out it is make this call using `exec`:

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode.common import I2of5
```

But because the import is only done dynamically `py2exe` doesn't know about the need for this package.

So how do you fix it? Simply add `'reportlab.graphics.barcode.common'` to your package list, that should help `py2exe` locate the module it is looking for.

Comment: Cheers B8vrede. That seems to have solved that particular error but I just get another error with another missing module as part of the reportlab package. Is there something that I can do to import all the necessary modules?

Comment: I think the best thing for your case is to make sure that your imports are specific, so not `from reportlab.graphics import shapes` but `from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawings` (or whatever you need from shapes). This prevents loading all kind of unnecessary Classes that all have dependencies that can cause import errors.

Comment: I will give it a try. I import the package pylabels (https://github.com/bcbnz/pylabels) so I hope there is nothing in there that is importing functions that could cause problems.

Comment: That package will probably don't cause any issues as it uses normal import calls, unlike Reportlab.